# How to blink image in back to back 4 image in android

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I want to blink the images in back to back upto 4 images. this means that 1 image is shown n gone and when 1st image is gone then show the 2nd image and when 2nd image is gone then show 3rd image this process is continue for my requirement and images are loaded in run time.

Comment: What do you mean by runtime ?

Comment: total  images is 56 but show only 4 image in one time. so choose 4 image  randomly in run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :-

```
     private void loadingAmin(final TextView loading) {

            final Animation pokeLoadingAnim = new Animation() {

                    int step = 0;

                    @Override
                    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                                    Transformation t) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
                            if (interpolatedTime == 0) {
                                    loading.setText("Loading");
                                    step = 1;
                            }
                            if ((interpolatedTime / 0.3) > step) {
                                    loading.setText(loading.getText() + ".");
                                    ++step;
                            }

                    }
            };
            pokeLoadingAnim.setDuration(2000);
            pokeLoadingAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            pokeLoadingAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            pokeLoadingAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            loading.startAnimation(pokeLoadingAnim);
    }
```

call this method

```
            TextView layout = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.loading);
            loadingAmin(layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

**If images are url based or getting online then**

```
int pos=0;
    String[] urlsOfimages;

     private Handler blnkHandler = new Handler() {

          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           switch(msg.what) {
           case STOPSPLASH:
               //Set image here form the urlsOfimages[pos]
            img.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
            resumeMessage = new Message();
            resumeMessage.what = RESUMESPLASH;
            resumeHandler.sendMessageDelayed(resumeMessage, SPLASHTIME);

            pos++;

//Logic could be improve by your self by sending What pram, i just give you and idea
            if(pos==5)
                pos=0;

           }
          }
         };

         private Handler resumeHandler = new Handler() {

          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           switch(msg.what) {
           case RESUMESPLASH:
            img.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            stopMessage.what = STOPSPLASH;
            blnkHandler.sendMessageDelayed(stopMessage, SPLASHTIME);
           }
          }
         };
```

and in create method

```
blnkHandler.sendMessageDelayed(STOPSPLASH, SPLASHTIME);
```

**If images are offline available in drawable folder then**

```
AnimationDrawable myAnimationDrawable;
    public void loadAnimation()
    {
        ImageView myAnimation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
         myAnimationDrawable= (AnimationDrawable)myAnimation.getDrawable();
        myAnimationDrawable.start();        
    }
```

in XML like anim_loading.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list android:id="@+id/progress_horizontal" android:oneshot="false" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_0" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_2" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_3" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_4" android:duration="500" />
     </animation-list>
```

If your images have to be chosen at run time then create Animation List grammatically as

```
    animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img3), 1000);
    animation.setOneShot(false);

    ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R,id.img);
    imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
    imageAnim.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            animation.start();   
        }
    });
```

Comment: then you have to use handler

Comment: My image is stored in Drawable and get random image in drawable